# In Symfony is there a way to access the app_dev information with REST

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to optimize my app and have been using the profiler you get with app_dev to be very useful, especially the doctrine panel.

Is there any way to log this information to a file so I can see what is happening when I POST / PUT to a RESTful controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you using development enviorment (`app_dev.php`) profiler works independend of the fact of displaying toolbar unless you force to disable it via config.

You can view all the profile data after successfull or failed request via `http://your.app.address/_profiler/`

If it is not enough there is a way to

1. [Change profile storage engine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/storage.html)
2. [Access profile during local tests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html)